# Reference variable assignment logic

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Okay, so I'm making a function that reduces a rational number by calculating the greatest common factor, and then returns the new numerator and denominator after reducing/simplifying. Ex: 24/60 to 2/5.

```
void reduce(int &num, int &den){
  int remainder = num % den;

  while(remainder!=0){
    num = den;
    den = remainder;
    remainder = num % den;
    cout << "gcf: " << remainder << endl;
    break;
  }
    num = num / remainder;
    den = den / remainder;
  
}
```

The function should return num = 2 and den = 5. However, for some reason, it's returning num = 5 and den = 2.

My main function looks like this

```
int main() {
    int num = 24;
    int den = 60;
    reduce(num, den);
    cout << num << " " << den;
    // Output: 
    // gcf: 12
    // 5 2
```

Comment: Why not use `std::gcd`?

Comment: An unguarded `break` statement in a loop makes for a very short short time spent in the loop.

Comment: @eerorika I could, but in theory how would I do it this way (what Im doing wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing `num` and `den` inside `while` loop. That value should not be changed.

Please store `num` and `den` variables inside other variable and do the operation using those values as follows.

```
void reduce(int &num, int &den){
  int remainder = num % den;

  int tempNum = num, tempDen = den;
  while(remainder != 0){
    tempNum = tempDen;
    tempDen = remainder;
    remainder = tempNum % tempDen;
    cout << "gcf: " << remainder << endl;
    break;
  }
  num = num / remainder;
  den = den / remainder;
}

int main() {
    int num =24;
    int den = 60;
    reduce(num,den);
    cout << num << " " << den;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might even extract the loop into its own function `gcd` (that you can replace by `std::gcd` if available (C++17) and allowed).